# pygame function only works once, doesn't loop

Tags: python, pygame

I have a pause menu for a game im working on for school. If the user clicks 'p' it launches the pause menu. And the pause menu has a function that if a user clicks a button the user will be launched back into the game. Problem is after they are launched into the game the 'p' function to pause doesn't work anymore. I'm not sure if i looped it correctly.

the pong game

```
   import pygame

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

pygame.init()

size = 800,600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Basketball Shootout")

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def player1(x1, y1, xsize, ysize):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [x1, y1, xsize, ysize])

def player2(x2, y2, xsize, ysize):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [x2,y2,xsize,ysize])

def ball(ballx, bally):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, [ballx,bally],20)

def Score1(score1):
    font = pygame.font.Font("Minecraft.ttf" ,50)
    text = font.render(str(score1), True, white)
    screen.blit(text, [160, 550])

def Score2(score2):
    font = pygame.font.Font("Minecraft.ttf" ,50)
    text = font.render(str(score2), True, white)
    screen.blit(text, [610, 550])

x1 = 20
y1 = 175
xsize = 35
ysize = 150
speed1 = 0

x2 = 740
y2 = 175
speed2 = 0

ballx = 550
bally = 250
speedx = 8
speedy = 5

score1 = 0
score2 = 0

bg = pygame.image.load("pongbg2.png")
rect1 = pygame.Rect(50,510,100,50)

def pausescreen():
    import pausescreen

display_game = True
game_page = 1


while not done: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), rect1)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                speed1 = -10
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                speed1 = 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                speed2 = -10
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                speed2 = 10

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                speed1 = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                speed1 = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                speed2 = 0
            if event.key ==  pygame.K_DOWN:
                speed2 = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                pausescreen()




    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    player1(x1, y1, xsize, ysize)
    player2(x2, y2, xsize, ysize)
    ball(ballx,bally)
    Score1(score1)
    Score2(score2)

    y1 += speed1
    y2 += speed2
    ballx += speedx
    bally += speedy

    if y1 < 0:
        y1 = 0

    if y1 > 350:
        y1 = 350

    if y2 < 0:
        y2 = 0

    if y2 > 350:
        y2 = 350

    if ballx+20 > x2 and bally-20 > y2 and bally+20 < y2+ysize and ballx < x2+3:
        speedx = -speedx

    if ballx-20 < x1+35 and bally-20 > y1 and bally+20 < y1+ysize and ballx > x1+38:
        speedx = -speedx

    if bally > 477 or bally < 23:
        speedy = -speedy

    if ballx < 13:
        score2 += 1
        ballx = 350
        bally = 250

    if ballx > 750:
        score1 += 1
        ballx = 350
        bally = 250




    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

now here is my pause menu code.

```
import pygame
import sys

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
size = [800, 600 ]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Basketball Shootout")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Rectangles
rect1 = pygame.Rect(300,300,205,80)
rect2 = pygame.Rect(300,400,205,80)

#Font
font3 = pygame.font.Font("Minecraft.ttf", 40)

def playerpong():
    import playerpong



while not done: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True


        screen.fill(BLACK)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, rect1)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, rect2)


        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                if rect1.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    playerpong()
                if rect2.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    pygame.quit()

        clock.tick(60)

        pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What is the `pausescreen` module? And `def pausescreen(): import pausescreen` looks highly suspicious. You're importing a module to pause the game? That seems incredibly oddly structured.

Comment: Yes, this is the root of the problem. You are executing code by importing a module. This only works the first time you import. That's why you can't get it to run again. All the top-level code in the pause module should be in a function, you should import the module once at the top, and call the function when you want to execute that code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are importing your pause screen from another program which creates a problem as you can import a library only once. You can try to put your pause screen code in the function instead of calling it but if you insist, you can put your pause_screen code in a function and do a `from pausescreen import name_of_function` so whenever you need to call that code just write `name_of_funtion()`